# Why is it valid jsonschema for $id to be a path (i.e. end with a /)

Tags: jsonschema

The [jsonschema test suite](https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite) contains many test cases.

This [test case](https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/blob/6afa9b38d84d45550ec703123eb4e8ec67a8ae75/tests/draft2020-12/refRemote.json#L79)

```json
            "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
            "$id": "http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/",
            "items": {
                "$id": "baseUriChange/",
                "items": {"$ref": "folderInteger.json"}
            }
```

demonstrates a base-uri change with the "$id" field, which changes the base uri of the  sub-schema
in `#/items` to `http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/baseUriChange/`.

Clearly this should test if the below reference resolves to `http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/baseUriChange/folderInteger.json`.

The confusing part is however that the schema under `#/items` is now referred to by a path (note the trailing slash) and not a file. So its canonical uri `http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/baseUriChange/` is a semantically a path, but refers to an actual object with content (the schema).

This makes no sense to me and I find it confusing.

Is this actually allowed in jsonschema (I guess so)? And it is common in places where uris are used or is there any rationale for this descision?

Edit: In principle the same base uri change functionality can be achieved by giving file names

```json
            "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
            "$id": "http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/abc",
            "items": {
                "$id": "baseUriChange/xyz",
                "items": {"$ref": "folderInteger.json"}
            }
```

Then the "$ref" will still resolve to `http://localhost:1234/draft2020-12/baseUriChange/folderInteger.json`. So why is it ok to omit file names?

See [relative uri examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Resolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test with a folder path exists because it's something that can be (and probably has been) done.

There are a lot of these edge case tests that don't align with best practice, actually.  The test suite isn't supposed to illustrate how to write schemas.  It's intended to ensure implementation behavior, even in weird scenarios.

It's not recommended to do these things, obviously, but the tests ensure implementations handle such things properly if they do happen.